# How to resolve JavaScript heap out of memory error?

Tags: javascript, heap-memory

I have been getting this error while trying to batch the payload fetched for my get API. The payload is large and I have tried to increase the size using --max-old-space-size=3072. But it doesn't work. What can be done to resolve this?

[image: JavaScript heap out of memory error]

Comment: You might wanna look for any memory leaks in your code.

Comment: Don't post pictures of your error message, they can't be searched for and they're not accessible. Post your actual error message and the relevant code instead.